# Could someone please provide a possible reason for an invalid expression error. Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a simple regex in a file. The code is as follows -

```
for all_keys in keywords:
        if re.search(r'(%s-deletion\s.*?\s%s)' % (all_keys, gs), s, re.I|re.S):
            file1.write(file)
            file1.write('\n')
```

Here, `gs` is another string variable and `s` is the string in which this matching is to be done.

On executing the code, it gives the following error -

> File "D:/M.Tech work/finding occurences of rules.py", line 214, in cl
>       ***if re.search(r'(%s-deletion\s.*?\s%s)' % (all_gs, gs), s, re.I|re.S):***
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
>       ***return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)***
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
>       ***raise error, v # invalid expression***
>
> ***error: unbalanced parenthesis***

I don't seem to understand what the mistake could be. Is there a mistake with the regex code or the parenthesis? I tried asking in the chat but couldn't get a meaningful response. Thanks!!

Comment: You need to escape the `all_keys` and `gs`. `if re.search(r'(%s-deletion\s.*?\s%s)' % (re.escape(all_keys), re.escape(gs)), s, re.I|re.S):`

Comment: Hey @stribizhev, here you go again, posting an answer as a comment :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It is a dupe, I prefer to close questions where a solution is so evident. Were it a bit more complex, I'd post an answer.